# clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreFoundation'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova

I am developing an cordova iOS application which was working fine 
till now but suddenly today it generated an error "clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreFoundation'"

can someone help me with this
thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you import the core foundation library?

Comment: Please add the error as text. Otherwise nobody can search it.

Answer (score 1):

go to `Xcode -> project -> Targets -> Build settings -> Liking -> OTHER_LDFLAG`.  Here set the arguments  ands framework name.

ex : above add argument as `"-weak_Framework"` or `"-force_load"` and its value below as `"CoreFramework".`